# Golang - Docker API - parse result of ImagePull

Tags: docker, go, docker-api

I'm developing a `Go` script that uses the `Docker API` for the purposes of my project. After I login to my repository, I pull the Docker image I want, but the problem is that the [ImagePull](https://godoc.org/github.com/moby/moby/client#Client.ImagePull) function returns an instance of [io.ReadCloser](https://godoc.org/io#ReadCloser), which I'm only able to pass to the system output via:

```
io.Copy(os.Stdout, pullResp)
```

It's cool that I can see the response, but I can't find a decent way to parse it and implement a logic depending on it, which will do some things if a new version of the image have been downloaded, and other things if the image was up to date.
I'll be glad if you share your experience, if you have ever faced this problem.

Comment: Does the response have a standard format ? If so, you can use [json.Decoder](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder) to decode it to a struct and do what you want based on the values in the struct.

Comment: Actually it's something like a stream. I'm new to `Go` so I'm not really sure :)

Comment: Can you add an edit with a sample response output, I haven't worked on docker, just have a high level understanding.

Comment: I can't directly print it with `fmt.Print()`, because I get `&{0xc4202d42c0 {0 0} false <nil> 0x62f8b0 0x62f840}`, so the only option is to pass it to stdout, which gives me a couple of lines like this: `{"status":"Extracting","progressDetail":{"current":1081344,"total":3160552},"progress":"[=================\u003e                                 ] 1.081 MB/3.161 MB","id":"3c947192b06a"}`. As I said before, it's something like a stream, not a static data, that can be simply parsed as a native JSON object.

Comment: Why not [list images](https://godoc.org/github.com/moby/moby/client#Client.ImageList) before and after the pull? then compare images ids in order to know if the image was updated.

Comment: @Robert Yeah, that's the workaround I'm currently using, but I want to use the official way (if there is one, of course) :)

Comment: Could you show the code?

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky The code I'm using is exactly the same as the one used in the `moby` [tests](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/client/image_pull_test.go#L185-L187)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@radoslav-stoyanov before use my example do

`# docker rmi busybox`

then run code

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/docker/distribution/context"
    docker "github.com/docker/engine-api/client"
    "github.com/docker/engine-api/types"
    "io"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    // DOCKER
    cli, err := docker.NewClient("unix:///var/run/docker.sock", "v1.28", nil, map[string]string{"User-Agent": "engine-api-cli-1.0"})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    imageName := "busybox:latest"

    events, err := cli.ImagePull(context.Background(), imageName, types.ImagePullOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    d := json.NewDecoder(events)

    type Event struct {
        Status         string `json:"status"`
        Error          string `json:"error"`
        Progress       string `json:"progress"`
        ProgressDetail struct {
            Current int `json:"current"`
            Total   int `json:"total"`
        } `json:"progressDetail"`
    }

    var event *Event
    for {
        if err := d.Decode(&event); err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }

            panic(err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("EVENT: %+v\n", event)
    }

    // Latest event for new image
    // EVENT: {Status:Status: Downloaded newer image for busybox:latest Error: Progress:[==================================================>]  699.2kB/699.2kB ProgressDetail:{Current:699243 Total:699243}}
    // Latest event for up-to-date image
    // EVENT: {Status:Status: Image is up to date for busybox:latest Error: Progress: ProgressDetail:{Current:0 Total:0}}
    if event != nil {
        if strings.Contains(event.Status, fmt.Sprintf("Downloaded newer image for %s", imageName)) {
            // new
            fmt.Println("new")
        }

        if strings.Contains(event.Status, fmt.Sprintf("Image is up to date for %s", imageName)) {
            // up-to-date
            fmt.Println("up-to-date")
        }
    }
}
```

You can see API formats to create your structures (like my `Event`) to read them here https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.27/#operation/ImageCreate

I hope it helps you solve your problem, thanks.

Comment: Thank you @Vitaly! Your approach seems good, so I will try it and let you know if it works for me.

Comment: As I'm about to reward you with the bounty, I'd be glad if you improve your answer with an example of how you'd catch if a new version of the image was downloaded or the existing one was up-to-date.

Comment: @RadoslavStoyanov I've updated the code, I think you could create func from it :-)

Answer (score 10):

You can import [`github.com/docker/docker/pkg/jsonmessage`](https://godoc.org/github.com/moby/moby/pkg/jsonmessage) and use both [JSONMessage](https://godoc.org/github.com/moby/moby/pkg/jsonmessage) and [JSONProgress](https://godoc.org/github.com/moby/moby/pkg/jsonmessage#JSONProgress) to decode the stream but it's easier to call
[DisplayJSONMessagesToStream](https://godoc.org/github.com/moby/moby/pkg/jsonmessage#DisplayJSONMessagesToStream): it both parses the stream and displays the messages as text. Here's how you can display the messages using stderr:

```
    reader, err := cli.ImagePull(ctx, myImageRef, types.ImagePullOptions{})
    if err != nil {
            return err
    }
    defer reader.Close()

    termFd, isTerm := term.GetFdInfo(os.Stderr)
    jsonmessage.DisplayJSONMessagesStream(reader, os.Stderr, termFd, isTerm, nil)
```

The nice thing is that it adapts to the output: it updates the lines if this a TTY (the way `docker pull` does) but it doesn't if the output is redirected to a file.

Comment: This is great and helps a lot! Also don't forget that `DisplayJSONMessagesStream` also parses errors and returns an error with the error message in case of an error.

Answer (score 2):

I have used similar approach for my purpose (not a moby client). Typically idea is same for reading stream response. Give it a try and implement yours.

Reading stream response of any response type:

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(pullResp)
defer pullResp.Close()  // pullResp is io.ReadCloser
var resp bytes.Buffer
for {
    line, err := reader.ReadBytes('\n')
    if err != nil {
        // it could be EOF or read error
        // handle it
        break
    }
    resp.Write(line)
    resp.WriteByte('\n')
}

// print it
fmt.Println(resp.String())
```

---

However your sample response in the comment seems valid JSON structure. The [json.Decoder](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder) is best way to read JSON stream. This is just an idea-

```
type ImagePullResponse struct {
   ID             string `json"id"`
   Status         string `json:"status"`
   ProgressDetail struct {
     Current int64 `json:"current"`
     Total   int64 `json:"total"`
   } `json:"progressDetail"`
   Progress string `json:"progress"`
}
```

And do

```
d := json.NewDecoder(pullResp)
for {
   var pullResult ImagePullResponse
  if err := d.Decode(&pullResult); err != nil {
    // handle the error
    break
  }
  fmt.Println(pullResult)
}
```