# Disable verbose stdout in Docker Golang SDK for client.ImagePull()

Tags: docker, go, sdk

When pulling an image with `ImagePull()`, there is extensive stdout in the terminal showing the progress of the Pull, i.e.;

```
{"status":"Downloading","progressDetail":{"current":6433248,"total":7964517},"progress":"[========================================\u003e          ]  6.433MB/7.965MB","id":"ae5cee1a3f12"}
```

```golang
func PullImage(imageName string) bool {
    ctx := context.Background()
    cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.FromEnv, client.WithAPIVersionNegotiation())
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
        return false
    }

    //TODO: Need to disable Stdout!!
    log.Info("\t\tPulling image " + imageName)
    out, err := cli.ImagePull(ctx, imageName, types.ImagePullOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
        return false
    }
    defer out.Close()

    io.Copy(os.Stdout, out)

    log.Info("Pulled image " + imageName + " into host")

    return true
}
```

I have searched the [documentation](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/client/image_pull.go#L22) and haven't found a way to disable StdOut or change verbosity.

I don't really understand the `io.Copy(os.Stdout, out)` line, but disabling it causes no image to be pulled, as far as I can tell.

How can we hide the output from `ImagePull()`?

Comment: I don't see any output when running [this](https://pastebin.pl/view/00fe482a)

Comment: I tried with `_, err = cli.ImagePull(ctx, os.Args[1], types.ImagePullOptions{})`, but the image is not pulled into my machine.

Comment: What do you mean? Did you remember to pass the image name as commandline arguments to my script? I'm not telling you how to solve your problem, I'm just showing you an example script that is practically identical to yours where that problem doesn't occur, as a way to show you that the problem that you describe doesn't reproduce.

Comment: Thanks, the script helps, but still confused. I see the image does get pulled with `docker image ls`, but *only* after CTRL-C on your script with the infinite loop. I think what I'm after is a way to handle the returned [ReadCloser](https://godoc.org/io#ReadCloser) object which is new for me.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452679/golang-docker-api-parse-result-of-imagepull) gets really close to what I was looking for - block the process until image is pulled, and finally print status done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't really understand the io.Copy(os.Stdout, out) line, but disabling it causes no image to be pulled, as far as I can tell.

`io.Copy` simply reads all data from an `io.Reader` (in this case an `io.ReadCloser` which is also an `io.Reader`) and writes it into an `io.Writer`.

My understanding is that if you don't perform this step, `main` returns before `ImagePull` gets a chance to finish in the background.

However, if you do perform `io.Copy`, the copying keeps `main` busy long enough for the pull to actually finish.

In my example in the comments above, I kept `main` busy with a `for` / `sleep` loop instead.

The reason you see all the output is because... well, you copy the output of `ImagePull` to `Stdout` with `io.Copy(os.Stdout, out)`, so it's no surprise we see the output of `ImagePull` in stdout.

If instead we copied all output into some "blackhole" that makes the output disappear, we'd keep `main` busy while the copy is happening while suppressing all of its output.

One way to do that is to use `io/ioutil`'s `ioutil.Discard`. This is an `io.Writer` that simply throws away all data written to it.

So simply replace you `io.Copy(os.Stdout, out)` line with the following:

```
import {
    "io/ioutil"
}

io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, out)
```

Comment: Tested and works, thanks! I implemented event handling and logging as well according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452679/golang-docker-api-parse-result-of-imagepull)